# adding watermark- limitation

Tags: java, sejda

I started using Sejda for adding watermark for large volume of pages. Unfortunately below exception shows up :

```
Task failed. Reason was: TaskPermissionsException: Permission MODIFY is not granted.
```

According to information from [`sejda sdk web`](http://sejda.org/), there is no limitation when it comes to this task.  Could You please advise on the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Solved:Problem was connected with security settings of given pdf document